# How can I add Google Fonts in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, font-family

How can I add my Google fonts in the Magento2 head in layout file?

Does anyone have the dea?

Comment: this is not working anymore -please read this article http://nwdthemes.com/2016/06/16/magento-2-add-google-font/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add a Google Font to the Magento 2 like an ordinary external css: 
https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Quick_Start
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css

**Example:**

Open your file `<theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

Add the Google Fonts like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <!-- Add local resources -->
    <css src="css/my-styles.css"/>

    <!-- The following two ways to add local JavaScript files are equal -->
    <script src="Magento_Catalog::js/sample1.js"/>
    <link src="js/sample.js"/>

    <!-- Add external resources -->
<css src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" src_type="url" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" src_type="url" />

    <!-- Google Fonts -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Srisakdi" src_type="url" /> 
</head>
```

Comment: A note on this that you need rel="stylesheet" on the Google link for them to work (in Firefox, at least), and it also helps to specify the font weights, so <link src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,700" src_type="url" rel="stylesheet"  />

Comment: Why do you try to load javascript in a link tag? `<link src="js/sample.js"/>` ??

Comment: Actually we don't need type="text/css" to make it work.